# how to identify contact in my journey not sent a particular message

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey which has reporting some failures. I  need to send email to the failed contacts. How can i identify contacts in the journey not sent a particular message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they marked as 'Not Sent' if so there is an data extract you can run, its outlined here: '[Report on 'Not Sent' contacts through Journey Builder Emails](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313980&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)'

> Under the 'Configuration' tab ensure that at minimum these are checked (others can be added as necessary :
> Extract Not Sent
> Extract Subscribers
> Extract Unsubs

You can also use [Journey History](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_history.htm&type=5) and filter by failed status:

> Status The reason the contact entered or did not enter the journey, or why another action occurred. Failed status includes what caused the failure.

Or you can also compare against who was sent the email by leveraging the [_journey and _sent data views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_by_email_across_versions.htm&type=5)

```
cast(s.EventDate as date) as [Date],
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName',
ja.ActivityExternalKey,
count(s.SubscriberID) as [Sends]
from [_Sent] s
join [_JourneyActivity] ja 
on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
join [_Journey] j
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
join [_Subscribers] su
on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID
where ja.ActivityType in  ('EMAIL','EMAILV2')
and j.JourneyName = <JourneyName>
and s.EventDate > dateadd(dd,-7,getdate())
group by j.JourneyName,j.JourneyID,cast(s.EventDate as date),ja.ActivityName,ja.ActivityExternalKey
```